# Using template parameters to create a list of arguments which are passed to another function

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am creating a system where users can create applications by defining pieces of data (called resources) and functions (called systems) which act on the resources. I want the user to purely provide a function pointer of a certain type, and from that type I want to deduce which resources need to be passed to this function.

Here is some code for context:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

using TypeID = size_t;

class Type
{
public:
    template <class T>
    static TypeID ID()
    {
        static TypeID id = s_Counter++;

        return id;
    }

private:
    inline static TypeID s_Counter = 0;
};

struct Resource
{
   virtual ~Resource() = default;
};

template <typename T>
struct Res : public Resource
{
    inline static const TypeID ID = Type::ID<T>(); // Type::ID<T>() just returns a unique ID for every type
    T Data;
};

class Application
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<TypeID, std::unique_ptr<Resource>> m_Resources;
    std::vector<void(*)()> m_Systems;

public:
    template <typename T>
    void AddResource()
    {
        m_Resources[Res<T>::ID] = std::make_unique<Res<T>>();
    }

    template <typename T>
    T& GetResource()
    {
        return m_Resources[Res<T>::ID]->Data;
    }

    template <typename... Resources>
    void AddSystem(void (*pSystem)(Resources...))
    {
        m_Systems.push_back([pSystem]() {
            pSystem(/*Here, for every parameter in the parameter pack Resources, 
                    I want to call GetResource<>() with the appropriate template parameter*/);
        });
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    int a;
    float b;
};

void system(Foo foo, int num, float val)
{
    /*do stuff with foo, num and val*/
}

int main()
{
    Application app;

    app.AddResource<Foo>();
    app.AddResource<int>();
    app.AddResource<float>();

    app.AddSystem(system);
}
```

In the `AddSystem` function, I want to convert a list of template parameters such as `<int, float, Foo>` into a list of function calls `GetResource<int>(), GetResource<float>(), GetResource<Foo>()` so that the return values of these functions are then passed into the user-defined function `pSystem`. This example should result in the line `pSystem(GetResource<int>(), GetResource<float>(), GetResource<Foo>());` being generated.

Is there a portable way to do this? Such as a function the standard library provides?

If there is another obvious way of achieving the same result please let me know too, this design isn't set in stone yet.

Comment: what is `m_Systems` ? What is `m_Resources`? Please post a [mcve]. Make sure the code does not have errors that distract from the actual question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai updated the question to provide more context. I also added exactly what I want the generated code to look like.

Comment: `Type::ID<Data>` and then `T Data` makes no sense. You can see many more errors of your code here https://godbolt.org/z/a4jE351de.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai sorry for that... Added more things and made sure godbolt.org is happy with the code. The only error it gives now is with the part I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass `Get<Args>...` to the function pointer you can use pack expansion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void foo(int a,float b,double c) {
    std::cout << a << b << c;
}

template <typename T> int get() { return 0; }



template <typename ...Args>
void bar(void(*f)(Args...)) {
    f( get<Args>()...);  // calls f(get<int>(),get<float>(),get<double>())
}

int main() {
    bar(foo);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know pack expansion could work this way. Thank you!